# Append Firebase data to an array in Swift ios

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I don't know what I am doing wrong! I just simply want to take data from Firebase database and iterate for each result and put them into an array. I have tried serval different approaches. But they all return results adding one at a time to the array. I have data like below:

```
    {
      "1400001" : {
        "HHtype" : 3,
        "Sesgrup" : 4,
        "lg_Et harcaması" : 0,
        "lg_Total Harcama" : 3.11
      },
      "1400002" : {
        "HHtype" : 1,
        "Sesgrup" : 4,
        "lg_Et harcaması" : 1.2,
        "lg_Total Harcama" : 3.15
      },
      "1400004" : {
        "HHtype" : 3,
        "Sesgrup" : 4,
        "lg_Et harcaması" : 1.18,
        "lg_Total Harcama" : 3.06
      },
      "1400005" : {
        "HHtype" : 4,
        "Sesgrup" : 3,
        "lg_Et harcaması" : 2.21,
        "lg_Total Harcama" : 3.74
      },
      .......
```

And, I am using a code that is below :

```
func sen(){
        var rootRef: FIRDatabaseReference!
        var refHandle: UInt!
        var haneRef: FIRDatabaseReference!
        var numbersArray = [Int] ()



        rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        haneRef = rootRef.child("SES2014")


        haneRef.queryOrderedByChild("lg_Et harcaması").queryLimitedToLast(4).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            let hhtype = snapshot.value!["HHtype"] as? Int
            numbersArray.append(hhtype!)
            print(numbersArray)



        })

    }
```

￼￼And, the result is:

```
[3]
[3, 1]
[3, 1, 4]
[3, 1, 4, 4]
```

I want to get only the last array:  [3, 1, 4, 4]

How can I do this ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func sen(){
        var rootRef: FIRDatabaseReference!
        var refHandle: UInt!
        var haneRef: FIRDatabaseReference!
        var numbersArray = [Int] ()



        rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        haneRef = rootRef.child("SES2014")

        let queryCount = 4
        haneRef.queryOrderedByChild("lg_Et harcaması").queryLimitedToLast(queryCount).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            let hhtype = snapshot.value!["HHtype"] as? Int
            numbersArray.append(hhtype!)
            queryCount -= 1
            if queryCount <= 0 {
                print(numbersArray)
            }



        })

    }
```

Comment: It will wrong if your ref doesnt have enough 4 child

Comment: Don't worry, my ref has 9000 child. I posted here only 4. Thanks again

Comment: I have  another question. Can you look at the other post 'answer' please?

Comment: Sorry, I cant answer now due to driving. I will read it later :)