# Append Firebase data to an array using queryEqualToValue in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a question about [Append Firebase data to an array in Swift ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39386899/append-firebase-data-to-an-array-in-swift-ios). When I run this code with using `queryEqualToValue` for data given in the hyperlink, it gives number of elements that `queryCount` has. However, I want to all elements into an array.

For example, when I run `kısıt(3)`, I want to get all `HHtype` values in case of `Sesgrup = 3`. And, store these elements in an array. Can you help me on this?

I have data like below:

```
{
  "1400001" : {
    "HHtype" : 3,
    "Sesgrup" : 4,
    "lg_Et harcaması" : 0,
    "lg_Total Harcama" : 3.11
  },
  "1400002" : {
    "HHtype" : 1,
    "Sesgrup" : 4,
    "lg_Et harcaması" : 1.2,
    "lg_Total Harcama" : 3.15
  },
  "1400004" : {
    "HHtype" : 3,
    "Sesgrup" : 4,
    "lg_Et harcaması" : 1.18,
    "lg_Total Harcama" : 3.06
  },
  "1400005" : {
    "HHtype" : 4,
    "Sesgrup" : 3,
    "lg_Et harcaması" : 2.21,
    "lg_Total Harcama" : 3.74
  },
  ....... (9000unit)
```

The code of last answer :

```
func kısıt(sesNotoSet: UInt){

    var rootRef: FIRDatabaseReference!
    var haneRef: FIRDatabaseReference!
    var numbersArray = [Int] ()

    self.sesNo = sesNotoSet



    rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    haneRef = rootRef.child("SES2014")

    var queryCount : UInt = sesNotoSet
    haneRef.queryOrderedByChild("Sesgrup").queryEqualToValue(queryCount).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot)

        if let HHtypeDict = snapshot.value! as? [String:AnyObject]{
            for each in HHtypeDict{
                numbersArray.append(each.1["HHtype"] as! Int)
            }

            queryCount -= 1
            if queryCount <= 0 {
                print(numbersArray)
            }


        }

    })



}
```

The given error : `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` and `print(snapshot)` only is:

```
Snap (1400005) {
    HHtype = 4;
    Sesgrup = 3;
    "lg_Et harcamas\U0131" = "2.21";
    "lg_Total Harcama" = "3.74";
}
```

However, the snapshot should have 425 elements like that

Comment: This is very confusing "When I run this code with using queryEqualToValue for data given in the hyperlink, it gives number of elements that queryCount is. However, I want to all elements into an array. Can you help me on this." support it with some example!!!

Comment: Thanks your feedback. I updated it

Comment: Basically you just grab the snapshot variable like you are doing.                 for (var item in snapshot) { print(item) }    This may or may not help. Just worth trying what the completion block gets back.

Comment: What is the result that you are getting now...?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
  func kısıt(sesNotoSet: UInt){

    var rootRef: FIRDatabaseReference!
    var haneRef: FIRDatabaseReference!
    var numbersArray = [Int] ()

    self.sesNo = sesNotoSet



    rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    haneRef = rootRef.child("SES2014")

    var queryCount : UInt = sesNotoSet
    haneRef.queryOrderedByChild("Sesgrup").queryEqualToValue(queryCount).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in


        if let HHtypeDict = snapshot.value! as? [String:AnyObject]{
           for each in HHtypeDict{
           numbersArray.append(each.1["HHtype"] as! Int)
              }

        queryCount -= 1
        if queryCount <= 0 {
            print(numbersArray)
        }

      }

    })



}
```

Comment: There is an error(Type '(String, AnyObject)' has no subscript members for each["HHtype"]) on the code "numbersArray.append(each["HHtype"] as! Int)"

Comment: I have updated my answer , but update your question with your firebase DB JSON tree structure... Otherwise this is as far i can help you..

Comment: Also print the snaphot you recieve in `observeEventType ` block and paste it in your Q above.. Question not here in comments..